# Kotlin: How to produce an If statement dependant on two textBoxes

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a simple random character generator, for NPCs.
I need to pull a random name from an already defined array of names, but only if the Sex and Race are met.

For example, if it generates a Human Male, it will pull from the list of Human Male names. So it needs to check the Sex and Race of the character.

Both are pulled from arrays of their own, but I am having trouble getting the app to pull from the array results, to then pull from the correct name array.

I'm pretty new to this kind of coding, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HI Jack, welcome.   You should show the code you have completed so far.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data class `User`

   `data class User(var name: String, var sex: Char, var race: String)`
2. Add your all users into a list and after selecting sex and race, filter the list with specified conditions which returns filtered users.
3. Then get random item from filtered list using [Random.next(int)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/index.html).

```
val list = mutableListOf<User>()
list.add(User("Jack", 'M', "RACE1"))
//.....
list.add(User("Jill", 'F', "RACE2"))

val sex = 'M'
val race = "RACE1"

//assuming at least user will be available to meet below conditions
val randomUser = list.filter { it.sex == sex && it.race == race }.let {
    it[Random.nextInt(it.size)]
}
log("Selected user name ${randomUser.name}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Without looking at your code, we don't know how you're implementing your logic. But what I would do in your case is:

1. Create a method returning a NAME of type String. This method will receive SEX and RACE.
2. Add listeners to both SEX and RACE drop down to know when the user selected either a SEX or a RACE.
3. When the user selects either a SEX or RACE, check if the user has already selected from the other drop down. If the user has selected from both dropdowns, pass the selected SEX and RACE to the method you created from Step 1.